Question about an exercise showing in the set of prime ideals in commutative ring  has a minimal element with respect to inclusion
Background
The following is taken from Basic Abstract Algebra* by: Bhattacharya, Jain Nagpaul and Abstract Algebra from Dummit and Foote
[From:  Bhattacharya, Jain Nagpaul]
Definition: A right (left) ideal $I$ in a ring $R$ is called minimal if $(i)$ $I\neq \{0\}$, and $(ii)$ if $J$ is a nonzero right (left) ideal of $R$ contained in $I$, then $J=I$.
[From Dummit and Foote]
Exercise  Assume $R$ is a commutative.  Prove that the set of prime ideals in $R$ has a minimal element with respect to inclusion (possibly the zero ideal)  [Use Zorn's Lemma.]
Questions
I have two quick questions regarding the Exercise from above.
$1.$  Is the minimal element for set of prime ideal refer to in the exercise is the same as the same as formulated from the one in Bhattacharya, Jain Nagpaul text's Definition preceding it, with the only difference being I replace everywhere in that definition the word "ideal" with "prime ideal"?
$2.$  The Exercise asks the reader to use Zorn's Lemma, which requires one to create a total order/chain, an upper bound.  But in the exercise it says with respect to the inclusion relation.  But can the inclusion relation be the reverse inclusion instead?
Thank you in advance.


Is the minimal element for set of prime ideal refer to in the exercise is the same as the same as formulated from the one in Bhattacharya, Jain Nagpaul text's Definition preceding it

No: a minimal prime ideal is one which does not properly contain any other prime ideal. It can be, in fact, zero.
Minimally makes sense in any poset.  One such poset is the collection of all prime ideals which might contain the zero ideal. Another poset is the poset of nonzero right ideals.
“Minimal” used to refer to left/right ideals is always meant as “minimal nonzero.”

But can the inclusion relation be the reverse inclusion instead?

Zorn’s lemma involves a poset, and reverse inclusion is as good as a poset as inclusion. That is precisely what you want to do for the prime ideal exercise. Go ahead!

thank you for the clarification.  When I tried to find a proper definition of "minimal prime ideal" in Dummit and Foote, it refer me to an exercise.  Hence my post.
